# Generating truth tables for basic logic circuits

Tags: language-agnostic, logic, boolean-logic

Let's say I have a text file that looks like this:

```
<number> <name> <type> <inputs...>
1   XOR1    XOR     A   B
2   SUM     XOR     1   C
```

What would be the best approach to generate the truth table for this circuit?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you have available, and how big your file is.

Perl is optimized for reading files and generating simple text output.  It doesn't have a library of boolean operators, but they're easy enough to write.  I'd use that if I just wanted text-in, text-out.

If I wanted to display the data online AND generate a results file, I'd use PHP to read the data and write the table to a CSV file that could either be opened in Excel, or posted online in an HTML table.

If your data is in a REALLY BIG data file, I'd use SQL.

If your data is in a really huge file that you want to be accessible to authorized users online, and you want THEM to be able to create truth tables, I'd use Oracle's APEX to create an easy interface for them to build their own truth tables and play around with the data without altering it.

If you're in an electrical engineering environment, use the tools designed for your problem -- Verilog or similar.

Whatcha got?  Whatcha wanna do with it?

-- Ada

Comment: I prefer using C#. I already have the code to 'parse' the input text file. I just don't know where to start in terms of actually 'simulating' it. The output can simply be a text file with inputs and output values

Answer (score 0):

> I prefer using C#. I already have the code to 'parse' the input 
>   text file. I just don't know where to start in terms of 
>   actually 'simulating' it. The output can simply be a text file
>   with inputs and output values – Don 12 mins ago

How many inputs and how many outputs in the circuit you want to simulate?

The size of the simulation determines how it can most easily be run.  If the circuit is small(ish), you can enter the inputs and circuit values into vector arrays, then cross them to get the output matrix.

Matlab is ideal for this, as it was written for processing arrays.

Again:  Whatcha got, and whatcha wanna do with it?

-- Ada

Comment: It has to be 'dynamic' to a degree. I just need a few pointers on how to actually go about simulating the logic. I.e., how would I turn something like the text file I have in the OP into: (A XOR B) XOR C. or something

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: In C# the xor notation is   --   a^b  --  Is that all you really need?  Just to see the notation?  Or do you need code to read a file, process its contents, and write it into a new file?

Comment: No, I need a suggestion on how to turn the text file into a 'circuit'. The text file I gave is just an example. I have the code to read the file and process the contents. I want to be able to 'convert' the contents into a truth table. So if I were using the file I gave as an example, I would want to turn that into: (A XOR B) XOR C, and then output the truth table.

Comment: Download Verilog.  It's pretty easy to learn, and it's designed to do exactly what you need it to do.

Comment: This is an assignment. The prompt is given a file that looks like the one I posted in the OP, write a program to generate its truth table.

Comment: Ah!  So A and B and C are ALL inputs?  Then you have 12 input lines -- because A, B, C, and 1 are all in hexadecimal format.

Comment: Yes, A, B, and C are all 'generic' inputs. i.e: 000, 001, 010, 011 -> 111. I want the program to generate the truth table for SUM, which is (A XOR B) XOR C

Comment: C# allows you  to specify that a value is in hexadecimal format. You can XOR or AND or OR  or whatever these values directly, as long as C# knows that they're hex values.

Comment: I know how to 'apply' the logic, I just don't know how to start in terms of 'sorting' the inputs so that my program can generate a truth table. My program needs to be able to handle multiple inputs and outputs, it can't be 'hard coded'.